# WiX- Harvested with heat, what else needs to be added?

Tags: xml, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am very new to the WiX suite, and I have been assigned to make an installer that takes a software folder (all files inside a complete `ComponentGroup`), installs it in the Program Files Directory, and makes some registry changes. I harvested the entire directory using 
`heat dir ../myApplication -gg -dr "ProgramFilesFolder" -ke -out ../setup.xml -cg "complete" -template product`.
 That seemed to work, and it gave me a functional file. However, when I run it through `candle` and `light`, it gives me a warning that the cabinet (`product.cab`) is empty, and it is-- the MSI flashes on screen and disappears without doing anything. My question is this: What else do I need to add in order for the installer to be functional?

my `Media` line is as follows:
`<Media Id ="1" Cabinet="Product.cab" EmbedCab = "yes"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "flashing" you are seeing is likely due to the fact that you didn't author any UI.  I blogged about this in "[Are Dialogs Optional Now??](http://blog.iswix.com/2007/04/are-dialogs-optional-now.html)" some 8 years ago and I was attacked for trolling (on my own blog??).

I suggest taking a look at [IsWiX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/).  The visual studio project templates ( scaffolding ) and graphical designers will write 99.9% of your XML for a basic functioning installer.   Additional stuff like environment variables, COM, registry will still need to be authored by hand.

Watch [IsWiX Web Site Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDf1kv8a-4) for a silent video showing how to author a web site, create an installer for it and test it in 3 minutes.